# Overflow: Hidden causing content layout issues

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a nice looking text-fade in effect for my website. The issue I am running into is caused by the user of overflow: hidden.

Here is my codepen demonstrating the problem:

https://codepen.io/camerongray6692/pen/zWBqZP

And to satisfy the 'codepen link must be accompanied by code...' rule:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <h1>Test Heading</h1>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5HEZhk0.png" class="imageReplacement"/>
  <div class="sectionSubheadings">
    <h3 class="test-subheading">This is test text. This is test text. </h3>
    <h3 class="test-subheading">This is test text. This is test text. This is test text.</h3>
    <h3 class="test-subheading">This is test text.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="special-text">
    <p>
     Suspendisse vel vehicula metus, et tincidunt ex. Nulla egestas cursus accumsan. In vitae egestas felis, id dignissim dui. Etiam scelerisque luctus imperdiet. Duis at mattis tortor. Nam at vulputate lorem. Donec hendrerit tempor pharetra. Nulla efficitur ipsum a lorem faucibus pharetra quis id ante. Sed magna turpis, efficitur vitae fringilla dictum, sollicitudin eget erat. Etiam bibendum sed nunc nec gravida.
    </p>
    <p>
      Quisque pretium lorem molestie lectus mattis ullamcorper. Donec lacinia consequat est nec tempus. Praesent et vehicula lacus. Vivamus arcu ex, vehicula ac diam sit amet, ullamcorper imperdiet leo. Donec pellentesque augue eget molestie pulvinar. Fusce et auctor urna. Vestibulum a fringilla orci.
    </p>
    <p>
      In congue, lacus eget fermentum congue, erat augue accumsan magna, quis euismod nunc enim a odio. Sed sagittis enim pharetra lectus fringilla accumsan. Proin consectetur tellus egestas suscipit posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean porttitor pharetra aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus sollicitudin sapien felis, quis lobortis neque molestie eget. Praesent ut felis sit amet velit ultrices venenatis. Vivamus nunc dolor, malesuada eu erat at, malesuada varius diam. Nam ac mi risus.
    </p>
    <p>
     Sed et lorem lobortis, varius est eu, molestie dui. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc consequat ut dolor sit amet vestibulum. Integer commodo laoreet turpis eu suscipit. Etiam vehicula ex id nibh vulputate vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ac nisl sed purus hendrerit condimentum.
    </p>
    <p>
      In congue, lacus eget fermentum congue, erat augue accumsan magna, quis euismod nunc enim a odio. Sed sagittis enim pharetra lectus fringilla accumsan. Proin consectetur tellus egestas suscipit posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean porttitor pharetra aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus sollicitudin sapien felis, quis lobortis neque molestie eget. Praesent ut felis sit amet velit ultrices venenatis. Vivamus nunc dolor, malesuada eu erat at, malesuada varius diam. Nam ac mi risus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="expand-button">
    Continue Reading
  </button>
```

CSS:

```
.imageReplacement {
  background-color: red;
  width:225px;
  height:225px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.test-subheading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
}

.special-text {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s ease;
   }

.special-text.-expanded {
  max-height: 1500px;
}

.special-text:not(.-expanded)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}

.special-text > p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".expand-button").on("click", function() {

  $(".special-text").toggleClass("-expanded");

  if ($(".special-text").hasClass("-expanded")) {
    $(".expand-button").html("Collapse Content");
  } else {
    $(".expand-button").html("Continue Reading");
  }
});
```

This is so close to the desired effect I am looking for, but I cannot figure out a way to get the text that appears after the image to wrap and use the space underneath the image.

If I set overflow:hidden to visible, the text wraps as expected. However, then the text does not disappear when clicking 'Collapse Content'. I have tried creating a wrapper around the special-text div and setting overflow-x to visible and setting overflow-y to hidden on the special-text div, but it acts exactly as if overflow was set to hidden.

Trying to change the overflow after the -expanded class has been added to the special-text results in the content moving around in a very jarring way during the animation.

If anyone could provide some guidance on how to accomplish this, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok After tons of trail and error, this is the only way I found to do exactly what you want

pen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrzpgY

This is not that flexible because you have to define a max-height on the container which need to be high enough to show the image but not too high that it shows too much text.

The main issue here is you are trying to show this in an unnatural as far as how the content works. You want the image to show which means it needs to be outside of the content and if it is outside then your floated image won't let your text wrap because the text is in a block element. The element must remain block because you need to give it a max height for animation.

We can't set overflow visible on expand because what it does is it just shows the content right away which is why you see that button in front of text because the text will just show, the animation is useless at this point.

While the below code works but it is not dynamic. I strongly suggest you make a compromise somewhere, either put the image with the text and have the fade hide part of the image or show the text on the left side like you had. The only other option is maybe use js to calculate height on click then set a bunch of things but I really think that is over complication for this

```js
$(".expand-button").on("click", function() {

  $(".row").toggleClass("-expanded");

  if ($(".row").hasClass("-expanded")) {
    $(".expand-button").html("Collapse Content");
  } else {
    $(".expand-button").html("Continue Reading");
  }
});
```

```css
.imageReplacement {
  background-color: red;
  width:225px;
  height:225px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.test-subheading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 320px;
overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s ease;
}

.row.-expanded {
  max-height: 1500px;
}

.row:not(.-expanded) .row-content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}

.special-text > p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-content">
      <h1>Test Heading</h1>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5HEZhk0.png" class="imageReplacement"/>
      <div class="sectionSubheadings">
        <h3 class="test-subheading">This is test text. This is test text. </h3>
        <h3 class="test-subheading">This is test text. This is test text. This is test text.</h3>
        <h3 class="test-subheading">This is test text.</h3>
      </div>

        <p>
         Suspendisse vel vehicula metus, et tincidunt ex. Nulla egestas cursus accumsan. In vitae egestas felis, id dignissim dui. Etiam scelerisque luctus imperdiet. Duis at mattis tortor. Nam at vulputate lorem. Donec hendrerit tempor pharetra. Nulla efficitur ipsum a lorem faucibus pharetra quis id ante. Sed magna turpis, efficitur vitae fringilla dictum, sollicitudin eget erat. Etiam bibendum sed nunc nec gravida.
        </p>
        <p>
          Quisque pretium lorem molestie lectus mattis ullamcorper. Donec lacinia consequat est nec tempus. Praesent et vehicula lacus. Vivamus arcu ex, vehicula ac diam sit amet, ullamcorper imperdiet leo. Donec pellentesque augue eget molestie pulvinar. Fusce et auctor urna. Vestibulum a fringilla orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          In congue, lacus eget fermentum congue, erat augue accumsan magna, quis euismod nunc enim a odio. Sed sagittis enim pharetra lectus fringilla accumsan. Proin consectetur tellus egestas suscipit posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean porttitor pharetra aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus sollicitudin sapien felis, quis lobortis neque molestie eget. Praesent ut felis sit amet velit ultrices venenatis. Vivamus nunc dolor, malesuada eu erat at, malesuada varius diam. Nam ac mi risus.
        </p>
        <p>
         Sed et lorem lobortis, varius est eu, molestie dui. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc consequat ut dolor sit amet vestibulum. Integer commodo laoreet turpis eu suscipit. Etiam vehicula ex id nibh vulputate vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ac nisl sed purus hendrerit condimentum.
        </p>
        <p>
          In congue, lacus eget fermentum congue, erat augue accumsan magna, quis euismod nunc enim a odio. Sed sagittis enim pharetra lectus fringilla accumsan. Proin consectetur tellus egestas suscipit posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean porttitor pharetra aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus sollicitudin sapien felis, quis lobortis neque molestie eget. Praesent ut felis sit amet velit ultrices venenatis. Vivamus nunc dolor, malesuada eu erat at, malesuada varius diam. Nam ac mi risus.
        </p>

    </div>
    <button class="expand-button">
        Continue Reading
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I tried this before I created the post. The issue with simply adding overflow: visible to the -expanded class is that it really throws off the fading animation. Without overflow: visible, when you click the 'Continue Reading' button the text appears to "fade in" behind the button. If you add overflow: visible, the text displays as soon as the button is clicked. This causes the text to briefly overlap the button until the button has moved down to its final location.

Comment: @CameronGray can the html change?

Comment: Yes it can. I have full control over the structure of this.

Comment: @CameronGray I updated my answer, it is an option but not really flexible

Comment: Well thank you for your effort spent on this. I agree that the best option is probably to find a happy compromise here. I knew what I was trying to accomplish kind of broke the mold of how content layout works, but I thought maybe there was an obvious solution I was missing.

Comment: Another option is to kill the animation and just show content on button click which gives the perception of fast loading. That would be really easy to do. The js approach is to again, have a set height at the start, then calculate the height of inner content then apply that height for animation but that's also setting height on the `.row` which contains the image and text.

Comment: I have tried the javascript approach on a different web page, but didn't like the strict requirements of having a set height. My goal is for this to be as responsive as possible so anywhere I can avoid setting hard values I do. I am going to go ahead and accept your answer, as I don't believe there really is a true "solution" to my issue.

Comment: @CameronGray for js, you would have what you have now, and on button click, calculate the height of the row, then set it to the container, then toggle expand class as you are now, make sure the overflow is visible for that class. Then calculate the height of `.row`, then set the container height to that, it should be the total height with all content expanded. Make sure container has transition on height. I think this should work. Then on collapse, you need to set the container height back to original row height

Comment: I actually ended up just doing away with the animation like you suggested. You are right, it just looks like a fast load and does not appear to be jarring or confusing to the user. I still get the gradient effect, hidden text, and text overflows under the image. Best of all worlds! Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Yea for future reference, have a look at this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdLmgv I just played around with it animating with js over 0.5 second